# Self referential list in python?

Tags: python, language-lawyer

While analyzing python list I got surprised when I saw something which is not possible in other programming language. Lets say I have a list called `my_list`

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Next when I'm doing like

```
my_list[9] = my_list  #I didn't seen such things possible in C/C++
```

And when I'm printing `my_list`, `my_list[9]` and `my_list[9][9]`, all these gives the same results.

```
my_list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [...]]
my_list[9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [...]]
my_list[9][9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [...]]
```

What I understood is that `my_list[9]` is **referring to same list** called `my_list` and `[...]` means **self referential list** i.e list pointing to same list as when you do `type(my_list[9])` it gives me `type` as `list`.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, [...]]
                              |
             Does it like self referential struct pointer concept of C ?
```

Above `my_list` example I just added for simple test run. I want to know how things like `my_list[9] = my_list` makes python code performance better. what is the actual intention behind this `my_list[9] = my_list` making possible in python ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can understand the dupe but is there a practical purpose for this being supported?

Comment: @roganjosh I don't see how it can be prevented while inserting...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So it's a quirk rather than an actual feature that could ever find practical use? That's what I was thinking anyway, I was just curious if this was actively permitted for some use that I couldn't see.

Comment: this could lead to infinite loops on, for instance, a recursive flatten algorithm. But if the recursion is controlled, it could be useful. And python allows to store every reference in a list, including its own (cannot be checked, that would be too costly)

Comment: Question heading may be same, I agree @Jean-FrançoisFabre but my intention of this question was to know what python wants to achieve by making it possible `my_list[9] = my_list`. since `list` is mutable so its possible or it can contains any data type.

Comment: okay but the intention doesn't show in the question. Re-reading the question, and it fits the duplicate very much. Maybe you should clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible because a list (like other containers) store *references*, and why not a reference of itself?

The `__str__` / `__repr__` functions have been protected against this to avoid infinite recursion, and show an ellipsis instead (`...`).

Why is it possible? Because it's not impossible. If Python were to prevent that, it would mean checking for self-referencing every time an object is added in the list. This would either be an additional O(n) storage overhead for maintaining a reference cache, or an O(n) time overhead for performing a reference search.

Answer (score 2):

Lists in python don't contain anything except references to objects (like a pointer). They can refer to any object including themselves.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So you are saying `list` actually doesn't contains values, it contains reference of those values ?

Comment: Python doesn't have values - in python everything are references - including normal variables, attributes, function parameters...

Comment: Thanks. I understood it doesn't store values in the list, it stores the references to those values. Can you get me deeper into intention behind python supporting self-referential list as by doing `my_list[9] = my_list` actual `list` got modified, that's not actual self referential concept of other programming language.

Comment: it is not an intention or a special support - it works because there is no special case, everything is an object so everything can be stored in a list, including the list itself