# python for loops: What does this does?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to python, i was working with python random module and for loops.

accidentally I typed this

```
from random import choice

secret_num = []
for i in range(4):
    num = choice(range(10))
    secret_num.append(secret_num)

print(secret_num)
```

instead of appending `num` to `secret_num list` i appended `secret_num`

but now i am curious what this program does.

I got this output:

```
[[...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

Comment: The “…” is basically a protection inside the print logic which prevents an infinite output. What actually happened is that the `secret_num` list is `[secret_num, secret_num, secret_num, secret_num]`, i.e. it contains itself four times – not as a copy but as a reference, so each of the inside elements _is the same list_ that contains itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secret_num = []` is an empty list that you are appending to itself (which technically turns it into a non-empty one). This is called self-referencing.

What is happening is that `secret_num` is storing itself as an object, but, since the size of secret_num is dynamic (as you add items to the meta-list, the sublists also increase in size), the lists are shown with `...` or the Ellipsis.

Note: It's not possible to print an object which has been modified with the insertion of itself, as it would enter infinite recursion. Think about it, if you modify the list by inserting itself into it, the new updated list that you are referring to would be inserted into itself as well, since you are only pointing to the object. This is why python uses the ellipsis (...) instead of the actual objects.

Read [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67239458/4755954) of mine, which talks about this in more detail.